# How to sum of each column in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am new to ssrs, I have a table that has record of student admissions, in report i have a matrix with row group on "school_branch" and column group on "classes", each class of each branch has specific number of class_section and students. My problem is that in last row of matrix i want to get total section and total student of each class of all branch, i have a picture that may clear my problem.

[image]

In this picture total sections are 64 of class "I", but it should be 17.
For this result I have try as

```
=RunningValue(Fields!totalSubclasses.Value,sum,"dataset1")
```

that give me wrong result

Comment: Why to RunningValue with dataset1? As it's matrix, showing your design will be more clear.

Comment: @Pinwar i have studied a little bit about ssrs, i do not know what i should do to get the total sections, can you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can add sub-totals at the end of a matrix.

However, there is an alternative for your solution.

Create another Matrix for your last section i.e. for Total (Remove Total section from first matrix) and place at the end where your first matrix ends.

Second Matrix will be the same as of first **except** the first group i.e. `Branch`.